# Behaviour of VPATH in makefile

Tags: makefile

As of I understand VPATH variable can hold list of search paths for the source files that needs to be compiled. Hence I am using VPATH in the same context, as in example code-snippet below.

```
SFILES= src1.c src2.c src3.c
VPATH= $(PATH-1)/src
```

The listed sources are present in my current directory where the Makefile exists as well as in $(PATH-1)/src. When I give **"make"**, I see the *sources in current directory taking precedence over VPATH*.

Is there anyway to override this behavior other than removing/relocating the sources in the current directory.

Comment: Would `SFILES= $(PATH-1)/src1.c $(PATH-1)/src2.c $(PATH-1)/src3.c` do?

Comment: That might help I think. I will try and let you know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid the answer is no. From GNU `make` documentation: if a file that is listed as a target or prerequisite *does not exist in the current directory*, make searches the directories listed in VPATH for a file with that name.